# Unexplicable #NUM Error in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Attempting to create a correlation matrix in excel, I made the following formula:

```
=CORREL(OFFSET(A2:A1001,0,ROW()-ROW(G2)),OFFSET(A2:A1001,0,COLUMN()-COLUMN(G2)))
```

`ROW()-ROW(G2)` and `COLUMN()-COLUMN(G2)` produce outputs of 0 and 0 respectively when evaluated at cell G2, and `CORREL(OFFSET(A2:A1001,0,0),OFFSET(A2:A1001,0,0))` produces a correlation of 1, but using `ROW()-ROW(G2)` and `COLUMN()-COLUMN(G2)` in the offset formula in place of 0 and 0 yields a #NUM error. Are these expressions not ultimately passing 0 to the column offset arguments of the offset function, and if they are, why is a #NUM error then returned?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `CORREL` is considering the internal final result of the `OFFSET` functions to not be numbers.

If simply fixing this is your goal, wrapping each `OFFSET` in a `VALUE` function will take care of it.

If looking for a reason why though, I cannot find anything, though I've only looked for about 10 minutes. Internally, the evaluation seems to produce array constants (so `{2}` for `ROW(2)` ending up with `{0}` as the column parameter vs. `0`. However, Excel is fully conversant with its own array constants(!) and the form is of a number, not a non-number (`{0}` vs. `{"0"}`), so there should be no difficulty in knowing number from non-number.

Further along the array constant thought, placing literal versions into the formula rather than the calculations (`{0}` rather than simply `0` or the calculations in the formula) produces a #VALUE! error instead. That makes it fairly clear though not definitive that the problem is not with Excel creating an array constant internally for evaluating the steps in the formula. So does using `F9` on each step to manually follow the process as it works nicely when one does so ending in a #DIV/0! error.

So definitely, something Excel ordinarily recognizes as a 0 IS being moved along internally and used, appropriately, as a number at every stage along the way, but at the end, it is not "number enough" for `CORREL` to use it. It is, however, "number enough" for `VALUE` to make `CORREL` happy.

An interesting glimpse into the inner workings. Not instructive, but interesting.

*(That's not utterly true:  instructive it is in that other functions might fail for no discernible reason and remembering this, and that wrapping the final (or earlier, as could happen perhaps) interim results in `VALUE` before presentment to the unhappy function might solve the problem. (Just the #NUM! problems, not others.))*

Comment: It's not to do with *number* vs *non-number*; rather *array* vs *non-array*. Arrays passed to `OFFSET`'s *rows* or *cols* parameters have always required prior 'dereferencing' with some suitable function: for example, with `A1:A3` containing numerics, `=OFFSET(A1,{0,1,2},0)`, will produce `{#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!}`, though `=N(OFFSET(A1,{0,1,2},0))` will return a valid array of numerics.